# Discord.py Translate message contents from Channel to Specific User ID's DMS

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am working on a Discord Bot that if the Prefix (In this case, $) is called, the entire following message is sent to a User's Direct Messages.
(user id removed for security)

```
async def on_message(message):
 if message.content.startswith('$ '):
      CONTENT = message.content
      async def sendDm():
         user = await client.fetch_user("USERID")
         await user.send(CONTENT)
```

However, upon doing this, The bot is unresponsive. I would like to know why this is happening, and what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got assistance from the Discord.py Discord.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content and message.content.startswith("$") and not message.author.bot:
        user = await client.fetch_user(user_id)
        await user.send(message.content)
```